# Generating relational algebra for unnested repeated records

Tags: apache-calcite

How would one go about generating relational algebra for a SQL stmt that looks like this?

```
SELECT
  id,
  (
  SELECT
    h.is_active
  FROM
    UNNEST(history.all_of_history) h
  WHERE
    start_date <= "2021-06-01" AND (end_date >= "2021-06-01" OR end_date IS NULL))
FROM
  `table`
```

---

`table` has two columns: `id` and `history`. `history` is a record and `history.all_of_history` is a repeated record with three fields (`is_active`, `start_date` and `end_date`)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are only interested in the logical plan, the relational algebra of the query that you mentioned, will be the following:

```java
    LogicalProject(id=[$0], $f1=[$SCALAR_QUERY({
    LogicalProject(is_active=[$0])
      LogicalFilter(condition=[AND(<=($1, 2021-06-01), >=($2, 2021-06-01))])
        LogicalTableFunctionScan(invocation=[UNNEST($1)], rowType=[RecordType(BOOLEAN is_active, DATE start_date, DATE end_date)])
    })])
      LogicalTableScan(table=[[scott, my_table]])
```

Here is the high level overview on how to create the RelNode:

1. You need to first define the row type of your table i.e `my_table`:

   1.1 Your row should look something like this:

   `RecordType(INTEGER id, RecordType:peek(BOOLEAN is_active, DATE start_date, DATE end_date) MULTISET history)`

   1.2 You need to observe the dataype of `history`. It needs to obey the definition of `UNNEST` sql function. Just to explain this post, I've considered `MULTISET` datatype.

   1.3 Lets assume that you are only interested in the logical plan, so you can create a simple table as follows:

```java
    Table tableImpl = new AbstractTable() {
      @Override
      public RelDataType getRowType(RelDataTypeFactory typeFactory) {
        RelDataType id = typeFactory.createSqlType(SqlTypeName.INTEGER);
        List<RelDataType> historyRecordDataTypes = Arrays.asList(
            typeFactory.createSqlType(SqlTypeName.BOOLEAN),
            typeFactory.createSqlType(SqlTypeName.DATE),
            typeFactory.createSqlType(SqlTypeName.DATE)
            );
        List<String> historyRecordFieldNames = Arrays.asList("is_active", "start_date", "end_date");
        RelDataType history = typeFactory.createStructType(StructKind.PEEK_FIELDS, historyRecordDataTypes, historyRecordFieldNames);
        return typeFactory.createStructType(Arrays.asList(id, typeFactory.createMultisetType(history, -1L)), Arrays.asList("id", "history"));
      }
    };
```

2. After creating the table and defining its `rowType`, you need to populate it in
   `schemPlus`. Lets just add the table that is created above, in the schema `scott` present in test suite of calcite.

   ```java
   rootSchema.getParentSchema().getSubSchema("scott")).add("my_table", tableImpl)
   ```
3. After creating the custom table and populating it in `schemaPlus`, you first need to create table scan of `my_table`

   ```java
   builder.scan("my_table");
   ```
4. Then you need to create the rel of unnest subquery. You need to use the `RelBuilder#functionScan(...)` API for this. According to the query mentioned in the post, the `unnestRelNode` will be the following:

```java
        builder.functionScan(SqlStdOperatorTable.UNNEST, 0, builder.field("history"));
        List<RexNode> innerQueryFilterPredicates = Arrays.asList(
            // start_date <= "2021-06-01"
            builder.call(
                SqlStdOperatorTable.LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL,
                builder.field("start_date"), builder.getRexBuilder().makeDateLiteral(new DateString("2021-06-01"))),
            // end_date >= "2021-06-01" OR end_date IS NULL
            builder.call(
                SqlStdOperatorTable.OR,
                // end_date >= "2021-06-01"
                builder.call(
                    SqlStdOperatorTable.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL,
                    builder.field("end_date"), builder.getRexBuilder().makeDateLiteral(new DateString("2021-06-01"))
                ),
                // end_date IS NULL
                builder.call(
                    SqlStdOperatorTable.IS_NULL, builder.field("end_date")
                )
            )
    
        );
        RelNode unnestRel = builder.filter(builder.call(SqlStdOperatorTable.AND, innerQueryFilterPredicates))
               .project(builder.field("is_active"))
               .build();
```

5. Lastly in order to create the final RelNode, you need to make the `unnestRel` into a scalar subquery:

```java
    RelNode finalRel = builder.project(builder.field("id"), builder.scalarQuery(b -> unnestRel))
           .build();
```